# NetBeans: eliminating gaps between text fields

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to make a 20x20 grid where I can make each square either black, white or blank. I also want to put a character in the square if it is white (this is for a crossword puzzle application).

I am using Java Swing in NetBeans 7.3 and my plan is to have a 20x20 set of text fields, but NB doesn't allow you to place the text field flush up against each other, there is always a small gap, which I do not want.

Does anyone know how to get rid of the gap or know if there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What layout manager are you using? Try using a GridLayout instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the component in GUI builder and select properties. There you can adjust components' settings.

Comment: Insets. But, I can't change this property with default layout of NetBeans. Only on another layouts, such as GridBagLayout.